# How to remove the axis marks in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have a plot don with ggplot. I don't need the axis value, which I successfully removed using `axis.text.x = element_blank()` and `axis.text.y = element_blank()`. However, I have been left wight the axis marks "the small lines at the end of each value in the x and y lines" I have pot them in small red circles for clarifications. I wounded if anyone have an idea of how to get red of those as well.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
weights1    <-read.csv ("./EN_ALPHA_WHIGHTS.csv")
ca          <- ddply(weights1, "comb", transform,  percent_weight = pers / sum(pers) *  100)
ggplot(ca, aes(x=comb, y=percent_weight, fill=alpha))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+xlab("")+ylab("")+theme(legend.position="none",axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_blank())+theme(legend.title=element_blank(),legend.text = element_text(colour = 'gray', angle = 45, size = 3, hjust = 3, vjust = 3))
```

Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
axis.ticks = element_blank()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DanielA.White Sorry, will word my responses more clearly in future - this was my answer. Thanks!